# How do I split these arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

```
$data = "google,98%,bing,92%,searchengine,56%,seo,85%,search,94%";
```

I want split thsese and get final result

```
google = 98%
bing = 92%
searchengine = 56%
seo = 85%
search = 94%
```

Comment: In what format do you want your final result? An associative array? An array of strings, one for each line? A single string containing new lines?

Comment: this is final result on a page I want to show  so and so got so and so percentage...actually for seo pupose

Comment: `str_replace(',', ' = ', str_replace('%,', "%\r\n", $str));` ;-))) Learn to ask questions properly.

Comment: it doesn't matter for what purposes you need this. But explains a lot though :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
$data = "google,98%,bing,92%,searchengine,56%,seo,85%,search,94%";
$dataSet = array_combine(array_map(create_function('$entry', 'return $entry[0];'),
                                   array_chunk(explode(",", $data), 2)),
                         array_map(create_function('$entry', 'return $entry[1];'),
                                   array_chunk(explode(",", $data), 2)));

foreach ($dataSet as $cType => $cPercentage) {
    echo $cType . " = " . $cPercentage;
}
```

Comment: yeah I getting it now...well some error previously..and I think he may edited the same.

Comment: @aron n: Quite alright, little bit complex perhaps, for what it is, but it is a useful technique.

Answer (score 4):

This will get you an associative array:

```
$out = array();
$parts = explode(',', $data);
for($i=0;$i<count($parts);$i++) {
   $out[$parts[$i]] = $parts[++$i];
}
```

Comment: well seems good but how do you get final result?? first one $out[$parts[$i]] does not return value

Comment: Try `var_dump`, `foreach ($out as $name => $percent)` or `echo $out['google']`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your output as a single string containing new lines you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$result = preg_replace('/([^,]*),([^,]*),?/', "$1 = $2\n", $data);
```

Output:

```
google = 98%
bing = 92%
searchengine = 56%
seo = 85%
search = 94%
```

See it working online at [ideone](http://ideone.com/fj9mp).

Comment: Fine if they only wanted it to change textual layout, if they actually need the data for something, bit more of a problem.

Comment: good one toot short but I need both value in different variable

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = "google,98%,bing,92%,searchengine,56%,seo,85%,search,94%";

preg_match_all("/(\w+),(\d+)%/", $data, $data_array, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($data_array as $item) {
    print $item[1]." = ".$item[2]."%<br />";
}
```

The parsing all happens in one line; the only looping is in the output. You can do `print_r($data_array)` to see how the array is structured in case you want to do different things with the data.

Also, if you want the percent sign included in the data, you can move it to the inside of the second parentheses pair. But if you leave it out (and just display it upon output) it will be easier to perform calculations on the data if you need to